# SSAS : Calculated Member based on a condition in the same row

Tags: ssas

I have this fact table

[image]

I want to create a calculated member like this : S = the sum of the "TOT_LIV" that have the "NUM_PROD" = 1

For example:

[image]

S should be equal to 50

How could I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a measure defined on this fact table named "TOT LIV", this measure has "Sum" defined as its aggregate method, and that `NUM_PROD` is a foreign key to a dimension named `Prod` having an attribute named `Num Prod` which I assume being based on the primary key of the dimension, and hence it would be 1 as well for the records that are references by the `NUM_PROD` primary key, you would use

```
([Measures].[TOT LIV], [Prod].[Num Prod].[1])
```

You see there is no 1:1 translation from SQL to MDX, a lot of things depend on cube setup, which predefines many behaviors that you have to repeat again and again in SQL queries (like the usage of `sum`).